# R data tables vlookup nearest date

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to do a vlookup in r using data.tables. I am looking up the value for a specific date, if it is not available I would like the nearest next value.

```
table1 <- fread(
          "id | date_created       
           1  |  2018-01-02
           1  |  2018-01-03
           2  |  2018-01-08
           2  |  2018-01-09", 
          sep ="|"
        )
        table2<- fread(
          "otherid       | date  | value
           1             |  2018-01-02 |   1
           2             |  2018-01-04 |   5    
           3             |  2018-01-07 |   3       
           4             |  2018-01-08 |   5         
           5             |  2018-01-11 |   3           
           6             |  2018-01-12 |   2",
          sep = "|"
        )
```

The result should look like:

```
table1 <- fread(
          "id | date        | value2
           1  |  2018-01-02 |  1
           1  |  2018-01-03 |  5
           2  |  2018-01-08 |  5
           2  |  2018-01-09 |  3", 
          sep ="|"
        )
```

**Edit**
I fixed it, this works:

```
table1[, value2:= table2[table1, value, on = .(date=date_created), roll = -7]]
```

Comment: `table1[, value2:= table2[table1, value, on = .(date=date_created), roll = -Inf]]`. Notes: 1) `roll`, not role, 2) `Inf` needs to be in caps, 3) `on` is fussy on the ordering of variables: needs to be `date=date_created`, i.e. the column in table2 needs to be mentioned first.

Comment: @OttoKässi thanks, it didnt like `inf` and you are right I needed to rearrange the order. Thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
table1[, value2:= table2[table1, value, on = .(date=date_created), roll = -7]]
```